# How to Delete Duplicate Elements from Dynamically Allocated String Array in C

Tags: c, malloc

I have created a program in C that reads in a word file and counts how many words are in that file, along with how many times each word occurs.

When I run it through Valgrind I either get too many bytes lost or a Segmentation Fault.

How can I remove a duplicate element from a dynamically allocated array and free the memory as well?

[Gist: wordcount.c](https://gist.github.com/MrRa1n/289b21d1d6b62864a3ae0211ad91c737)

```
int tokenize(Dictionary **dictionary, char *words, int total_words)
{

    char *delim = " .,?!:;/\"\'\n\t";
    char **temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(words) + 1);
    char *token = strtok(words, delim);

    *dictionary = (Dictionary*)malloc(sizeof(Dictionary) * total_words);

    int count = 1, index = 0;

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        temp[index] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(temp[index], token);

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);

        index++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < total_words; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < total_words; ++j)
        {
            if (strcmp(temp[i], temp[j]) == 0) // <------ segmentation fault occurs here
            {
                count++;

                for (int k = j; k < total_words; ++k) // <----- loop to remove duplicates
                    temp[k] = temp[k+1];

                total_words--;
                j--;
            }
        }


        int length = strlen(temp[i]) + 1;
        (*dictionary)[i].word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);

        strcpy((*dictionary)[i].word, temp[i]);
        (*dictionary)[i].count = count;

        count = 1;
    }

    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a reason for asking for [mcve]. It makes it easy for other people to help you faster. Otherwise people would see this much of code - and will stay away from it - because it is kind of like *"find the problem first - then solve it"*.

Comment: @coderredoc Thanks, I removed everything but the function in question.

Comment: You have modified the question and now I would consider the posted code is the one which might have the problem as per you.

Comment: `char **temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(words) + 1);` is unlikely what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @coderredoc This allocates the total number of bytes needed for the file being read in. When I remove this line and try to access `temp[index]` I get an Access Violation error

Comment: Well, I don't get one thing - why `sizeof(char)*strlen(words)` - a `char**` should point to beginning of the allocated memory `N` `char*`'s

Comment: [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) means an example that can be **compiled** and will produce the exact results that form the basis for your question. A function is of little help. For example, if the parameter who address was passed as `**dictionary` was previously allocated, `*dictionary = (Dictionary*)malloc(sizeof(Dictionary) * total_words);` creates a memory leak.

Comment: Earlier code was not MCVE I suppose, and it is expected that one would refine the problem to certain extent - not as is large code. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've included a link to the full code. Dictionary doesn't have any previous allocation.

Answer (score 3):

Without [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there is no guarantee that additional problems do not originate elsewhere in your code, but the following need careful attention:

```
    char **temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(words) + 1);
```

Above you are allocating **pointers** not words, your allocation is too small by a factor of `sizeof (char*) - sizeof (char)`. To prevent such problems, if you use the `sizeof *thepointer`, you will always have the correct size, e.g.

```
    char **temp = malloc (sizeof *temp * strlen(words) + 1);
```

(unless you plan on providing a *sentinel NULL* as the final pointer, then `+ 1` is unnecessary. You must also **validate** the return (see below))

Next:

```
    *dictionary = (Dictionary*)malloc(sizeof(Dictionary) * total_words);
```

There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Further, if `*dictionary` was previously allocated elsewhere, the allocation above creates a memory leak because you lose the reference to the original pointer. If it has been previously allocated, you need `realloc`, not `malloc`. And if wasn't allocate, a better way of writing it would be:

```
    *dictionary = malloc (sizeof **dictionary * total_words);
```

You must also validation the allocation succeeds *before* attempting to use the block of memory, e.g.

```
    if (! *dictionary) {
        perror ("malloc - *dictionary");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

In:

```
        temp[index] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token) + 1);
```

`sizeof(char)` is always `1` and can be omitted. Better written as:

```
        temp[index] = malloc (strlen(token) + 1);
```

or better, allocate and validate in a single block:

```
        if (!(temp[index] = malloc (strlen(token) + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc - temp[index]");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

then

```
        strcpy(temp[index++], token);
```

Next, while `total_words` may be equal to the words in `temp`, you have only validated that you have `index` number of words. That combined with your original allocation times `sizeof (char)` instead of `sizeof (char *)`, makes it no wonder there can be segfaults where you attempt to iterate over your list of pointers in `temp`. Better:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < index; ++j)
```

(the same applies to your `k` loop as well. Additionally, since you have allocated each `temp[index]`, when you shuffle pointers with `temp[k] = temp[k+1];` you overwrite the pointer address in `temp[k]` causing a memory leak with every pointer you overwrite. Each `temp[k]` that is overwritten should be freed before the assignment is made.

While you are updating `total_words--`, there still to this point has never been a validation that `index == total_words`, and in the event they are not, you can have no confidence in `total_words` or that you won't segfault attempting to iterate over uninitialized pointers as the result.

The rest appears workable, but after changes are made above, you should insure that the are no additional changes needed. Look things over and let me know if you need additional help. (and with a MCVE, I'm happy to help further)

---

**Additional Problems**

I apologize for the delay, real-world called -- and this took a lot longer than anticipated, because what you have is an awkward slow-motion logical train-wreck. First and foremost, while there is nothing wrong with reading an entire text-file file into a buffer with `fread` -- **the buffer is NOT nul-terminated** and therefore cannot be used with any functions expecting a **string**. Yes, `strtok`, `strcpy` or any string function will read past the end of `word_data` looking for the nul-terminating character (well out into memory you don't own) resulting in a SegFault.

Your various scattered `+1` tacked onto your `malloc` allocations now make a little more sense, as it appears you were looking for where you needed to add an additional character to make sure you could *nul-terminate* `word_data`, but couldn't quite figure out where it went. (don't worry, I straightened that out for you, but it is a big hint that you are probably going about this in the wrong way -- reading with POSIX `getline` or `fgets` is probably a better approach than the file-at-once for this type of text processing)

That is literally, just the tip of the iceberg in the problems encountered in your code. As hinted at earlier, in `tokenize`, you failed to validate that `index` equals `total_words`. This ends up being important given your choice of `delim` which includes the ASCII apostrophe (or single-quote). This causes your `index` to exceed the `word_count` any time a plural-possessive or contraction is encountered in the buffer (e.g. `"can't"` is split is `"can"` and `"t"`, `"Peter's"` is split into `"Peter"` and `"s"`, etc.... You will have to decide how you want to resolve this, I have simply removed the single quote for now.

Your logic in both `tokenize` and `count_words` was difficult to follows, and just wrong in some aspects, and your return type (`void`) for `read_file` provided absolutely no way to indicate a success (or failure) within. Always choose a return type that provides meaningful information from which you can determine is a critical function has succeeded or failed (reading your data qualifies as critical).

If it provides a return -- use it. This applies to all functions that can fail (including functions like `fseek`)

Returning `0` from `tokenize` misses the return of the number of words (allocated struts) in `dictionary` leaving you unable to properly `free` the information and leaving you to guess at some number to display (e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < 333; ++i)` in `main()`). You need to track the number of `dictionary` structs and member `word` that are allocated in `tokenize` (keep an index, say `dindex`). Then returning `dindex` to `main()` (assigned to `hello` in your code) provides the information you need to iterate over the structs in `main()` to output your information, as well as to free each allocated `word` before freeing the pointers.

If you don't have an accurate count of the number of allocated `dictionary` structs back in `main()`, you have failed in the two *responsibilities* you have regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. If you don't know how many blocks there are, then you haven't done (1) and can't do (2).

This is a nit about style, and while not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `Initialcaps`, `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Rather than carry on for another handful of paragraphs, I've reworked your example for you and added a few comments inline. Go though it, I haven't punishingly tested it for all corner-cases, but it should be a sound base to build from. You will note in going though it, your `count_words` and `tokenize` have been simplified. Try and understand why what was done, was done, and ask if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct{
    char *word;
    int count;
} dictionary_t;

char *read_file (FILE *file, char **words, size_t *length)
{
    size_t size = *length = 0;

    if (fseek (file, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) {
        perror ("fseek SEEK_END");
        return NULL;
    }
    size = (size_t)ftell (file);

    if (fseek (file, 0, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
        perror ("fseek SEEK_SET");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* +1 needed to nul-terminate buffer to pass to strtok */
    if (!(*words = malloc (size + 1))) {
        perror ("malloc - size");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fread (*words, 1, size, file) != size) {
        perror ("fread words");
        free (*words);
        return NULL;
    }

    *length = size;
    (*words)[*length] = 0;  /* nul-terminate buffer - critical */

    return *words;
}

int tokenize (dictionary_t **dictionary, char *words, int total_words)
{
    // char *delim = " .,?!:;/\"\'\n\t";    /* don't split on apostrophies */
    char *delim = " .,?!:;/\"\n\t";
    char **temp = malloc (sizeof *temp * total_words);
    char *token = strtok(words, delim);
    int index = 0, dindex = 0;

    if (!temp) {
        perror ("malloc temp");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(*dictionary = malloc (sizeof **dictionary * total_words))) {
        perror ("malloc - dictionary");
        return -1;
    }

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (!(temp[index] = malloc (strlen (token) + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc - temp[index]");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(temp[index++], token);

        token = strtok (NULL, delim);
    }

    if (total_words != index) { /* validate total_words = index */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: total_words != index (%d != %d)\n", 
                total_words, index);
        /* handle error */
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < total_words; i++) {
        int found = 0, j = 0;
        for (; j < dindex; j++)
            if (strcmp((*dictionary)[j].word, temp[i]) == 0) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        if (!found) {
            if (!((*dictionary)[dindex].word = malloc (strlen (temp[i]) + 1))) {
                perror ("malloc (*dictionay)[dindex].word");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            strcpy ((*dictionary)[dindex].word, temp[i]);
            (*dictionary)[dindex++].count = 1;
        }
        else
            (*dictionary)[j].count++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < total_words; i++)
        free (temp[i]);     /* you must free storage for words */
    free (temp);            /* before freeing pointers */

    return dindex;
}

int count_words (char *words, size_t length)
{
    int count = 0;
    char previous_char = ' ';

    while (length--) {
        if (isspace (previous_char) && !isspace (*words))
            count++;
        previous_char = *words++;
    }

    return count;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *word_data = NULL;
    int word_count, hello;
    size_t length = 0;
    dictionary_t *dictionary = NULL;
    FILE *input = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!input) {   /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!read_file (input, &word_data, &length)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file_read failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (input != stdin) fclose (input); /* close file if not stdin */

    word_count = count_words (word_data, length);
    printf ("wordct: %d\n", word_count);

    /* number of dictionary words returned in hello */
    if ((hello = tokenize (&dictionary, word_data, word_count)) <= 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no words or tokenize failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < hello; ++i) {
        printf("%-16s : %d\n", dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i].count);
        free (dictionary[i].word);  /* you must free word storage */
    }
    free (dictionary);  /* free pointers */

    free (word_data);   /* free buffer */

    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: **note:** I have your link to your code now and will edit or supplement if additional issue surface, but it will be a bit later this afternoon.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char) * strlen(token) + 1` is also  wrong in concept.  I'd expect `sizeof(char) * (strlen(token) + 1)`.  Of course makes no functional difference as `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Comment: Suggest commenting bad code _in_ the code snippets as `// bad code` or the like

Comment: Thanks for your help David, however I tried implementing your changes and nothing worked for me. I followed pgngp's solution and it works, however I still lose the memory pointer in the `temp[k] = temp[k+1];` line. If I free the memory then I cannot use the overwrite. Thanks

Comment: I'll be done with a meeting in about an hour, will update with more info then. Sit tight.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you need to do to make your code work:

1. Fix the memory allocation of `temp` by replacing `sizeof(char)` with `sizeof(char *)` like so:

   `char **temp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(words) + 1);`
2. Fix the memory allocation of `dictionary` by replacing `sizeof(Dictionary)` with `sizeof(Dictionary *)`:

   `*dictionary = (Dictionary*)malloc(sizeof(Dictionary *) * (*total_words));`
3. Pass the address of address of `word_count` when calling `tokenize`:

   `int hello = tokenize(&dictionary, word_data, &word_count);`
4. Replace all occurrences of `total_words` in `tokenize` function with `(*total_words)`. In the `tokenize` function signature, you can replace `int total_words` with `int *total_words`.
5. You should also replace the hard-coded value of `333` in your `for` loop in the `main` function with `word_count`.

After you make these changes, your code should work as expected. I was able to run it successfully with these changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've updated and it works. However, I'm still struggling to understand how to free the memory whilst removing duplicates in the `temp[k] = temp[k+1];` line of code

Comment: @TobyCook Another suggestion I have is that instead of doing `temp[k] = temp[k+1];`, which copies the pointer, use `strcpy`, which copies the actual string. Then you might be able to free the memory pointed to by `temp[k+1]`.